# SQL: select rows with conditions?

Tags: sql

Imagine I have the following table:

[image]

What I search is:

```
select count(id) where "colX is never 20 AND colY is never 31"
```

Expected result:

```
3 (= id numbers 5,7,8)
```

And

```
select count(id) where "colX contains (at least once) 20 AND colY contains (at least once) 31"
```

Expected result:

```
1 (= id number 2)
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? And is this a homework assignment?

Comment: This is no homework. I tried it with a select statement within another select query but i dont get the result I want to have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a "sets-within-sets" subquery.  The best approach is to use aggregation with a `having` clause, because it is the most general approach.  This produces the list of such ids:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having SUM(case when colX = 20 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and  -- colX is never 20
       SUM(case when colY = 31 then 1 else 0 end) = 0      -- colY is never 31
```

You can count the number using a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having SUM(case when colX = 20 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and  -- colX is never 20
             SUM(case when colY = 31 then 1 else 0 end) = 0      -- colY is never 31
     ) s
```

For the second case, you would have:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having SUM(case when colX = 20 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- colX has at least one 20
             SUM(case when colY = 31 then 1 else 0 end) > 0      -- colY has at least one 31
     ) s
```

Comment: - for the first case; change both `= 0` conditions to `> 0` for the second.

Answer (score 4):

First one:

```
select count(distinct id)
from mytable
where id not in (select id from mytable where colX = 20 or colY = 31)
```

Second one:

```
select count(distinct id)
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.coly = 30
where t1.colx = 20
```

Comment: I was very close to this, I did not know about "distinct". So both versions (yours and gordons) are working fine, i dont know which one to accept

Comment: @tombom OP asked for BOTH conditions at least once.

Comment: @Anonymous Chose the one that is most elegant... ie mine! :) Seriously though, my queries *are* more elegant and therefore easier to read, which makes them "better code". One of the most important measures of good coding is legibility, and brevity and cleanliness lead directly to legibility.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, yes, didn't get it right at first. But to be honest, Gordon's solution was easier to read and understand for me :) no offense...

Comment: @tombom no taken :) I don't mind at all. I admit I do favor brevity over legibility, but only because I've been doing this stuff for so long it's still clear to me. I fully get that another style might be better suited to a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Select COUNT(distinct ID)
from Test_Table1 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from Test_Table1 c 
        WHERE c.id = a.id 
        AND colX =20 AND coly= 31)

Select COUNT(distinct ID)
from Test_Table1 A
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from Test_Table1 c 
        WHERE c.id = a.id 
        AND colX =20 AND coly= 31)
```